# Operand Size Conflict in x86 Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I've just started programming in Assembly for my computer organization course, and I keep getting an `operand size conflict` error whenever I try to compile this `asm` block within a C program.

The `arrayOfLetters[]` object is a char array, so shouldn't each element be one byte?  The code works when I do `mov eax, arrayOfLetters[1]`, but I'm not sure why that works, as the `eax` register is 4 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

char findMinLetter( char arrayOfLetters[], int arraySize )
{
    char min;

    __asm{
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        mov dl, 0x7f        // initialize DL

        mov al, arrayOfLetters[1] //Problem occurs here

        mov min, dl        // read DL
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax
    }

    return min;
}

int main()
{
    char arrayOfLetters[ SIZE ] = {'a','B','c'};

    int i;

    printf("\nThe original array of letters is:\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        printf("%c ", arrayOfLetters[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("The smallest (potentially capitalized) letter is: %c\n", findMinLetter( arrayOfLetters, SIZE ));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the surrounding C code?

Comment: @DCoder I added it to the question, thanks!

Comment: when you use `mov` you are moving a word into destination register, however width of `al` is only one byte. You should use 'movb' instead IMO. Sorry can't debug your code, casue I don't have a Intel-styled assembler at hand. BTW, you mean `mov al, arrayOfLetters[1]` works or just can compile?

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea: This is the worst part of Intel's assembly language syntax - even though by virtue of having specified a byte register, `AL`, as destination the `BYTE` size for the load is implied, it's still necessary to explicitly state so. AT&T syntax for x86 uses operand size suffixes (`movb`, `movw`, `movl`, `movq`) which are simpler in this situation. And no, Intel Syntax doesn't know about `movb`.

Comment: @FrankH. Thanks for your comment. Not quite familiar with Intel Syntax, will have a look if time permits.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mov al, BYTE PTR arrayOfLetters[1]`.

You can compile the code with MSVC using `cl input.c /Faoutput.asm` to get an assembly printout - this would show that simply using `arrayOfLetters[1]` translates to `DWORD PTR` and you need to explicity state you want a `BYTE PTR`.