# C++ Inline asm operand size conflict error

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

```
CHAR cRet[256] = {0};

__asm
{
    push SomeHandle;
    mov ecx, 1;
    call SomeFunc;
    mov ecx, eax;
    call AnotherFunc;
    mov ecx,dword ptr ds:[eax+0x08];
    mov eax,dword ptr ds:[ecx+0x1C];
    mov cRet, eax;
}
```

I have two structures, this first structure + 0x08 points to the second structure and I want to read the second structure + 0x1C which is an string array (char*)

The compiler gives me `operand size conflict error` in this line :

```
mov cRet, eax;
```

In the first move I get the pointer of second structure successfully, the only problem is this error.

Whats going wrong ?

**EDIT :**
Problem solved by changing `CHAR cRet[256] = {0};` to `CHAR *cRet;`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070213/operand-size-conflict-in-x86-assembly

Comment: Try `mov eax, [ds:ecx + 0x1C]`

Comment: The error is actually on the line after it. You are storing a 32-bit register into an 8-bit array element

Comment: @KerrekSB Now I get this error too. `error C2422: illegal segment override in 'second operand'`

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, but what's the solution ?

Comment: OK, never mind. It depends on the specific dialect of your assembler...

Comment: Until we know what you want to do we cannot say what the solution is. Right now you are trying to store 32 bits of data into 8 bits of memory. Do you actually want to store only 8 bits? Do you want to store into 32 bits of memory? Do you want to copy a string?

Comment: illegal segment [ds:ecx + 0x1C] to ds:[ecx+0x1c]

Comment: @RaymondChen `ecx+0x1c` Is start of a char array. I want to fill my cRet array with `ecx+0x1c` array